# Variables stored in localstorage disappears when the page is refreshed

Tags: html, local-storage, page-refresh

This is a webpage where you can choose your backgroundpicture from three radio buttons. I want to save the chosen one in localstorage, so when the page is refreshed the last chosen background-image stands. That is not the case and I can not understand why, do you? Thanks in advance :)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html manifest="my.manifest">
    <head>
    <script src="modernizr.js"></script> 

    <script>
    function setBg() {
        myForm = document.getElementById("bgList");
        for (var i = 0; i < myForm.land.length; i++) {
            if (myForm.land[i].checked) {
                break
            }
        }
        document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('" + myForm.land[i].value + "')";

        if (Modernizr.localstorage) { 
            localStorage.setItem("background", i); 
            //alert(localStorage.getItem("background"));
        }
        else{
            alert("Can not be saved to localstorage!");
        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    // Sørger for å velge et bakgrunnsbilde når siden lastes
    <script src="modernizr.js">
        window.onload = function(e){
            mittLand = 0;
            if (localStorage.getItem("background") != null) {
                mittLand = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("background")); 
                alert(mittLand); 
            }
            myForm = document.getElementById("bgList");
            myForm.land[mittLand].checked=true;
            setBg();
        }
    </script>

    <form id="bgList">
        <h1>Velg ditt favorittland</h1>
        <input type="radio" name="land" value="norge.png" onClick="setBg()">Norge</input>
        <input type="radio" name="land" value="sverige.png" onClick="setBg()">Sverige</input>
        <input type="radio" name="land" value="danmark.png" onClick="setBg()">Danmark</input>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what part doesn't work? the alert display the selected option correctly, but since you are doing the alert before you set the background then the background is not style at the time of the alert, after you press the alert the image is set correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-latest.js"></script>

    <script>
        function setBg() {
            myForm = document.getElementById("bgList");
            for (var i = 0; i < myForm.land.length; i++) {
                if (myForm.land[i].checked) {
                    break
                }
            }
            document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('" + myForm.land[i].value + "')";

            if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
                localStorage.setItem("background", i);
                //alert(localStorage.getItem("background"));
            }
            else{
                alert("Can not be saved to localstorage!");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

// Sørger for å velge et bakgrunnsbilde når siden lastes
<script>
    window.onload = function(e){
        mittLand = 0;
        if (localStorage.getItem("background") != null) {
            mittLand = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("background"));
            alert(mittLand);
        }
        myForm = document.getElementById("bgList");
        myForm.land[mittLand].checked=true;
        setBg();
    }
</script>

<form id="bgList">
    <h1>Velg ditt favorittland</h1>
    <input type="radio" name="land" value="norge.png" onClick="setBg()">Norge</input>
    <input type="radio" name="land" value="sverige.png" onClick="setBg()">Sverige</input>
    <input type="radio" name="land" value="danmark.png" onClick="setBg()">Danmark</input>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Tried this code it works. Updated with modernizr

Comment: The alerts is just for testing and not important. What is important is that when I have saved the information in the localstorage, I want to retrive it after the page is refreshed. But the (localStorage.getItem("background") always resturs "null". I do not understand why.

Comment: I tried the code above it simply removes modernizer and it works

Comment: Thank you very much! =D Do you understand why it works without modernizer? Really want to understand all this :)

Comment: your script tag has a src attribute that makes it load modernizer again and ignore your window.onload code. remove that src attribute and it works just fine.